# When should I use Android Jetpack Compose's Surface composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

There's a [Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#surface) composable in Jetpack Compose which represents a [material surface](https://material.io/design/environment/surfaces.html). A surface allows you to set up things like background color or border but it seems that the same might be done using [modifiers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layout#modifiers). When should I use the Surface composable and what the benefits does it give me?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The [Surface](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#surface) composable makes the code easier as well as explicitly indicating that the code uses a [material surface](https://material.io/design/environment/surfaces.html). Let's see an example:

```kotlin
Surface(
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface,
    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.secondary),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    elevation = 8.dp
) {
    Text(
        text = "example",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    )
}
```

and the result:

[image: rendered Surface]

The same result can be achieved without Surface:

```kotlin
val shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
val shadowElevationPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { 2.dp.toPx() }
val backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface

Text(
    text = "example",
    color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    modifier = Modifier
        .graphicsLayer(shape = shape, shadowElevation = shadowElevationPx)
        .background(backgroundColor, shape)
        .border(1.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.secondary, shape)
        .padding(8.dp)
)
```

but it has a few drawbacks:

- The modifier chain is pretty big and it isn't obvious that it implements a material surface
- I have to declare a variable for the shape and pass it to three different modifiers
- It uses [contentColorFor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#contentcolorfor) to figure out the content color while Surface does it under the hood. As a result the `backgroundColor` is used in two places as well.
- I have to calculate the elevation in pixels
- `Surface` adjusts colors for elevation (in case of a dark theme) [according to the material design](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#properties). If you want the same behavior, it should be handled manually.

For the full list of Surface features it's better to take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#surface).

Comment: Blocking touch propagation might perhaps be the most important role of the Surface, compared to other content views/composables.

Answer (score 23):

`Surface` is a `Box` with a `Modifier.surface()` and material colors and elevation, it checks elevation of ancestors to be always on top of them, and only overload below blocking touch propagation behind the surface with `pointerInput(Unit) {}`.

```
@Composable
fun Surface(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape,
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(color),
    border: BorderStroke? = null,
    elevation: Dp = 0.dp,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val absoluteElevation = LocalAbsoluteElevation.current + elevation
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides contentColor,
        LocalAbsoluteElevation provides absoluteElevation
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .surface(
                    shape = shape,
                    backgroundColor = surfaceColorAtElevation(
                        color = color,
                        elevationOverlay = LocalElevationOverlay.current,
                        absoluteElevation = absoluteElevation
                    ),
                    border = border,
                    elevation = elevation
                )
                .semantics(mergeDescendants = false) {}
                .pointerInput(Unit) {},
            propagateMinConstraints = true
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

And `Modifier.surface()`

```
private fun Modifier.surface(
    shape: Shape,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    border: BorderStroke?,
    elevation: Dp
) = this.shadow(elevation, shape, clip = false)
    .then(if (border != null) Modifier.border(border, shape) else Modifier)
    .background(color = backgroundColor, shape = shape)
    .clip(shape)
```

Another interesting thing is it is `Box` with `propagateMinConstraints = true` parameter which forces first descendant to have same minimum constraints or dimensions

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
    onClick = {}) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
    ) {}
}

Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
    onClick = {}) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Green, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
        )

    }
}

Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

Box(
    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp)
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Green, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
        )

    }
}
```

In first example on `Surface` forces `Column` to have **200.dp** size even though it has `Modifier.size(50.dp)`.

In second example `Box` inside `Column` has 50.dp size because it's not a direct descendant of `Surface`.

In third example if we replace `Surface`(**Box with propagateMinConstraints true**) with `Box` it allows direct descendant to use its own constraints or dimensions.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Surface is the equivalent of `CardView` in view system.
By `Surface`, you can set elevation for the view (note that this is not the same with Modifier.shadow)

Comment: I think compose Card() is the equivalent of CardView

Comment: Thanks to say that, this let me more clear surface