# Android CircularProgressIndicator takes up full screen with compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a simple compose function i want to put a circularprogessindicator in the middle of the screen at 80dp x 80dp, its aligned to the top and takes up the full width.

```
@Composable
fun MyCircularProgress() {
    CircularProgressIndicator(
        modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp,80.dp)
    )
}
```

why isn't the modifier working

Answer (score 2):

I assume you put it inside a Surface with Modifier.fillMaxWidth() as direct descendant. `Surface` forces minimum constraints to direct descendant. You can check my answer out about Surface [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73030914/5457853).

You can put it inside a `Box` with `contentAlignment = Alignment.Center` to have a CircularProgressIndicator with 80.dp size and centered inside your Composable

```
@Composable
fun MyCircularProgress() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp, 80.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a shorter solution without nesting:

```
@Composable
private fun MyCircularProgress() = CircularProgressIndicator(
     Modifier
       .fillMaxSize()
       .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
       .size(80.dp)
)
```