# In Compose, how to set minimum height (minHeight) without consuming all available height?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, I have a card composable that I want to be a minimum of 100.dp tall. However, if I use `heightIn`, the card consumes all available height up until the max. How do I set a minHeight without consuming all height?

```
Surface(
    modifier = heightIn(100.dp, 9999.dp),
) {
    // Content
}
```

To be clear, what I want is the following algorithm:

```
height = if (contentHeight > minHeight) {
    contentHeight 
} else {
    minHeight
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `Modifier.defaultMinSize`

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 100.dp),
) {
    // Content
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I want, thanks!

Comment: With the latest version, the line should read as `Modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 100.dp)`

Comment: previously, I use `Modifier.height(..).width(..)` for this. I just know that `defaultMinSize` exist. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### Edit

> To be clear, what I want is the following algorithm:
>
> height = if (contentHeight > minHeight) {
> contentHeight  } else {
> minHeight }

`Modifier.height(contentHeight.coerceAtLeast(minHeight))` is the shortened algorithm.

When a Layout measures and places children it checks constraints. You can find [detail answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73258726/5457853) about how it works.

For instance column has minHegith = 100.dp, while maxHeight is your composable height in dp. If it's root it's height of screen in `dp`

```
Column(modifier=Modifier.heightIn(min=100.dp)) {
   Box(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Yellow))
}
```

For instance this Box covers whole space because it's min and max constraint is Column's `maxHeight`. In this case using `Modifier.heightIn()` won't limit, so you need `Modifier.height()` such as in my original answer with a fixed value or use custom layout to check and assign .

`layout(width, height){}` inside `Layout`.

But there is something to note with Surface that it forces minimum constraints to direct descendant, you can check my answer about Surface [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65918835/when-should-i-use-android-jetpack-compose-surface-composable/73030914#73030914).

```
Surface(modifier = Modifier.heightIn(min = 100.dp)) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(300.dp)
            .background(Color.Yellow)
    )
}
```

This Box in example will cover all of the height because of being Surface's direct descendant.

```
Surface(modifier = Modifier.heightIn(min = 100.dp)) {
   Column() {
       Box(
           modifier = Modifier
               .size(300.dp)
               .background(Color.Yellow)
       )
   }
}
```

This one will have 300.dp size while `Column` covers all available space of `Surface`

Comment: The example I gave was just what I need the algorithm to be, there isn't an actual variable named `contentHeight`. I could get that info by using a custom layout, but I would expect this common use case to be possible without going to that much trouble.

Comment: coerceAtLeast is extension function that is available for dp, float, int or double `public fun Float.coerceAtLeast(minimumValue: Float): Float {
    return if (this < minimumValue) minimumValue else this
}`

Comment: I don't think you understand, there isn't any variable called `contentHeight`, at least not without doing a custom layout.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an answer to the question.