# Setting minimum width in .widthIn() modifier does nothing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog

Having tried setting the min width of a column composable in a dialog, it does nothing. It always takes up the width specified as the max width, regardless of where I place the `widthIn()` modifier in the dialog composable and even if the content's width is smaller than the max width. How can I fix this?

```
@Composable
fun DeleteUnitTypeDialog(
    addShoppingListItemScreenViewModel: IAddShoppingListItemScreenViewModel,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    onConfirmClick: (ItemUnitType) -> Unit
) {
    val unitTypeList = addShoppingListItemScreenViewModel.itemUnitTypes.observeAsState().value

    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        properties = DialogProperties(
            dismissOnBackPress = true,
            dismissOnClickOutside = true,
            usePlatformDefaultWidth = false
        )
    ) {
        Surface(
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(4.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .widthIn(200.dp, 300.dp)
                    .heightIn(Dp.Unspecified, 500.dp)
                    .padding(top = 16.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Delete Unit Type",
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )

                Divider()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))

                LazyColumn {
                    if (addShoppingListItemScreenViewModel.itemUnitTypes.value?.size == 0) {
                        item { Text("List is empty.") }
                    }

                    itemsIndexed(
                        items = unitTypeList!!
                    ) { _, item ->
                        Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                            Text(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f), text = item.unitTypeName)
                            IconButton(
                                onClick = { onConfirmClick(item) }) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Delete,
                                    contentDescription = "Delete unit type"
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End) {
                    TextButton(onClick = onDismiss) {
                        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.dialog_cancel), fontSize = 16.sp)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because of `Surface`. It forces its constraints to first descendant.

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73030914/5457853) out.

Since its max dimensions are dialog max width and height these dimensions will be forced to `Column`. You can add another Compoasble between to test that your Column will have correct dimensios.

Comment: Will it fix this issue if I just remove the surface composable and use column by itself instead?

Comment: You can pass Column dimensions to Surface if you prefer or remove Surface it's up to you. I only pointed out a potential issue that happens because of this feature of Surface. It sets its dimensions to its direct child

Comment: I removed `Surface` and placed `.widthIn(100.dp, 300.dp)` for `Column` and still it ignores the min width of `100.dp` and always displays the dialog at `300.dp`. How can I fix this?

Comment: But the min height and max height values in the `heightIn()` modifier is obeyed.