# Android compose, Indicator size problem with coil

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil, asyncimageview

Recently, I try to migrate to Jetpack compose.

So, I want to show 'card' where has 'indicator' while loading
but I can't change 'indicator' size in 'SubcomposeAsyncImage'

```
@Composable
private fun SponsorDialogContent(
    imgUrl: String,
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(300.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(0.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
    ) {
        Box() {
            SubcomposeAsyncImage(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .heightIn(min = 200.dp),
                model = imgUrl,
                contentDescription = null,
                loading = {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.size(30.dp).align(Alignment.Center), progress = 1f)
                },
                alignment = Alignment.Center,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
            )

            CircularProgressIndicator(1f, Modifier.width(30.dp).align(Alignment.Center))
        }
    }
}
```

So. I have try the code below

```
@Composable
private fun SponsorDialogContent(
    imgUrl: String,
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(300.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight(),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(0.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
    ) {
        Box() {
            SubcomposeAsyncImage(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .heightIn(min = 200.dp),
                model = imgUrl,
                contentDescription = null,
                loading = {
                    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                        CircularProgressIndicator()
                    }
                },
                alignment = Alignment.Center,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Then, works well, but I don't know why
Does anyone know why?

I tried to find how to work this code but failed

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Jan Bina mentioned it has `propagateMinConstraints = true` which means it forces minimum constraints to its direct child only. I explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73030914/5457853) how it effects with Surface because Surface is a Box with `propagateMinConstraints = true`. You can try out these with Box and you will see the same outcomes

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
    onClick = {}) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
    ) {}
}

Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

Surface(
    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp),
    onClick = {}) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Green, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
        ) {}

    }
}

Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

Box(
    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp)
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Green, RoundedCornerShape(6.dp))
        ) {}

    }
}
```

[image]

In first example on Surface forces Column to have 200.dp size even though it has Modifier.size(50.dp).

In second example Box inside Column has 50.dp size because it's not a direct descendant of Surface.

In third example if we replace Surface(Box with propagateMinConstraints true) with Box it allows direct descendant to use its own constraints or dimensions.

And when you set Modifier.fillMaxWidth you set Constraints as minWidth = parent width, maxWidth = parentWidth

I answered about Constraint types [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73258726/5457853)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you browse the source code of `SubcomposeAsyncImage`, you will get to the point where you can see this:

```
BoxWithConstraints(
    modifier = modifier, // this is the modifier you passed to SubcomposeAsyncImage
    contentAlignment = alignment,
    propagateMinConstraints = true,
) {
    // image or your loading content based on state
}
```

So the behavior you describe is because of your modifier that has `heightIn(min = 200.dp)` and your progress indicator that ends up being direct child of this `Box` which has `propagateMinConstraints = true`.