# How to Set Button Height and Width in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to set button height and width in Jetpack Compose? I can't set button height and width.

```
Button(onClick = {  },
       modifier =  Modifier.size(width = 80.dp,height = 80.dp)
        ) {
        Text(text = "Lorem")
    }
```

The button takes up the entire screen.[image: The button takes up the entire screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `Column`, `Row` or any other layout. Read more about in here about [Layouts](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts). Basic Layouts comes from [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics#composable-functions).

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ButtonView() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Yellow)) {
        Button(
            onClick = { },
            modifier = Modifier.size(width = 80.dp, height = 80.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Lorem")
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I think the issue he had was having a Surface with Modifier.fillmaxSize as parent of button since Surface forces minimum Constraints to direct child

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74649544/5457853

Comment: Sounds good to me @Thracian