# Why is Card inside a Surface occupying max width?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using a Card inside Surface. The Surface has max width whereas the Card has width of 200 dp. But the Card is occupying max width i.e. the width of the Surface.

Here is my code

```
Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(300.dp)
                .padding(all = 12.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(corner = CornerSize(15.dp)),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(4.dp),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color.White)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.height(300.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            )
```

[image: This is the Preview]

Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 2):

Because `Surface` forces minimum `Constraints` to first descendant.

When you assign `fillMaxWidth()` min and max width  are equal to parent and when you assign`fillMaxHeight()` min and max height are equal to parent.

These min values passed to `Card` which is first descendant. If you remove those modifiers from Surface you will see that Card will use its own size Modifiers.

You can check out this answer about Surface for more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73030914/5457853

This one explains size modifiers and Constraints with detail.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316247/5457853